# Workers for phantomJs fail to start in a Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, highcharts, phantomjs, dockerfile

I am working on Dockerizing my node app which uses highcharts-export-server and creates images in my code. When I run the created image on my local machine the workers fail to start saying 
    `

```
phantom worker 7 error - /usr/src/app/node_modules/phantomjs- 
 prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: 1: 
/usr/src/app/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string.
```

The node version I am using is 8. I have also tried logging `platform` and `architecture` using `process.platform` and `process.arch` respectively inside my running container and using those values to set in Environment variables `PHANTOMJS_PLATFORM` and `PHANTOMJS_ARCH` in my dockerfile. I have also tried to install phantomJs separately using `RUN npm i -g phantomjs-prebuilt --unsafe-perm`. My Docker file looks like this currently.

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
ENV PHANTOMJS_BIN "/usr/local/bin/phantomjs"
ENV PHANTOMJS_PLATFORM "linux"
ENV PHANTOMJS_ARCH "x64"
ENV ACCEPT_HIGHCHARTS_LICENSE="YES"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    groff \
    less \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
    && apt-get clean

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install --upgrade awscli

RUN npm set strict-ssl false

RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: A bit looks like the problem with implementation and Docker setup. Please refer to this topic, and let me know whether it helps you: http://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/392

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but you can give it a try:

Run `npm i phantomjs-prebuilt --unsafe-perm` in you app folder, i.e. without `-g`. This should create a folder in `node_modules` called "`phantomjs-prebuilt`".
Also, check if you have `phantomjs` binary file created in the following path `node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/` once you run this command.